# Can I include a list of sub-menu pages in the content of the parent page?

Tags: 7, views, routes, nodes

I have a page that is the parent of a series of menu items, e.g. Projects, with some project pages as child items in that menu. I would like this parent page to automatically have the list of children in the content. Is this possible?

I have a block that I created that lists this menu via the Views module...if there is a way to use that, it might be an alternative.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By some coincidence, there is an article on how to [embed a block in the middle of your node body content](http://www.mydrupalexperience.com/block-region-middle-body-content#.UIczb6qljaE) on [Drupal Planet](http://drupal.org/planet) today.

It seems to me, though, that if you put the block at the top of your content and floated it with css, maybe with a border attribute, the result would perhaps be better than adding content to an arbitrary location inside the content.